# Damaged images, how to modify the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, broken-image

I have this code that displays a different image in place of a broken image link. The problem is that the script changes not only "damaged" images, but also images that display without a problem. How can I modify the code below?

```
 $("img").each(function () {
          if (
            (typeof this.naturalHeight != "undefined" &&
              this.naturalHeight == 0 &&
              this.naturalWidth == 0) ||
            this.readyState == "uninitialized"
          ) {
            $(this).attr(
              "src",
              "http://some-photo.blabla.png"
            );
          }
        });
```

I'm taking my first steps in programming.

Modifying the code so that it only fixes broken links, not all of them.

Comment: Do a bit of debugging, and start by figuring out, which part of the condition makes it true for non-"broken" images as well.

Comment: _When_ does this execute? An image might not have _finished_ loading yet, in which case your attempt to query its dimensions will likely fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be executed after the page is fully loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("img").each(function () {
      if (
        (typeof this.naturalHeight != "undefined" &&
          this.naturalHeight == 0 &&
          this.naturalWidth == 0) ||
        this.readyState == "uninitialized"
      ) {
        $(this).attr(
          "src",
          "http://some-photo.blabla.png"
        );
      }
    });
 }
```

Comment: It works but not completely. The script is not executed at the very end because some photos fail to load and are overwritten. Is there an option to delay the loading of the script by, for example, a few seconds? Please code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, of course with your help. Thank you!

```js
 var delayscript = function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("img").each(function () {
      if (
        (typeof this.naturalHeight != "undefined" &&
          this.naturalHeight == 0 &&
          this.naturalWidth == 0) ||
        this.readyState == "uninitialized"
      ) {
        $(this).attr(
          "src",
          "http://some-photo.blabla.png"
        );
      }
    });
 })
  };
setTimeout(delayscript, 10000);
```